# How to create descending left hand row numbers in a table (tr) with CSS

Tags: css

I use the method shown hear;
https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#lefthandheader
to add numbers to the left hand side of my table. And it works great by putting 1 at the top on the first row, 2 on the second and so on. However my table is time sensitive, and descending in order so the top row is actually the most current thing that occurred. I would like the left column to reflect that by having the highest number on top and descending to the bottom where the first event occurred.
Is there a simple way to modify the CSS to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My table in question is built using PHP/MYSql. It turns out that the quoted solution to number the left hand column has at least on option, you can add an option to the CSS like this.

```
table.sortable tbody {
    counter-reset: sortabletablescope 48;
}
```

Then reference it as demonstrated here:  [https://jsbin.com/yanihid/edit](http://%20https://jsbin.com/yanihid/edit)

The result is exactly as I needed it. Counting the rows starting at the highest number. All you have to do is know the count, an easy deal with PHP/MYSQL.